# Color specific items of Android Toolbar with styles.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar, android-styles

I've got the following problem: I'm trying to achieve an app design like instagram, where most of the app is using a light theme. However, I haven't found a method of coloring the toolbars text and icon elements like navigation drawer and back-button black.

When using the following style.xml

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="colorPrimary">#FAFAFA</item>
     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#BDBDBD</item>
     <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>

<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- Used to for the title of the Toolbar -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Used to for the title of the Toolbar when parent is Theme.AppCompat.Light -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Used to color the text of the action menu icons -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Used to color the overflow menu icon -->
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and this attribute for the toolbar:

```
android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
```

it produces the following design:

[image: design with custom toolbar theme]

As you can see, the navigation drawer is white and the tab titles are also white.

I also tried this style which would work fine but only if you don't explicitly set up a toolbar in your activity like this:

Activity Code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Style.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

When using this style with no explicit toolbar, the design looks like I want, however, I can't call the toolbar this way. If you set up the toolbar with Theme.AppCompat.Light, it will throw an error.

Also note the difference between the two styles: Theme.AppCompat.Light vs Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I just went with the standard android themes now like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/container"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/black"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

This is far easier than trying to set your own style.